# Generic function with specific constraints on the arguments

Tags: java, generics

I wish to create a function f which gets one argument called n of type `Number`. However I wish to also specify that n must be `Comparable` (which `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicLong` aren't). How can I write this function?

I tried this: `public static <T extends Number, Comparable<T>> void f(T n)` but this didn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple type parameter bounds must be separated with `&`, not `,`, e.g.:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> void f(T n)
```

A comma is used to separate multiple type parameter declarations, e.g:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>, S extends Comparator<T>> void f(T n, S m)
```

As per the JLS a type bound can be either:

- a type variable;
- or a class or interface, followed by one or more interfaces (and separated by `&`).

Therefore this works `T extends Number & Comparable<T>` and this does not `T extends Comparable<T> & Number`.

See: [JLS § 4.4: Type Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)

> ```
> AdditionalBound:
>   & InterfaceType
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. If no bound is declared for a type variable, `Object` is assumed. If a bound is declared, it consists of either:
>
> • a single type variable `T`, or
>
> • a class or interface type `T` possibly followed by interface types `I1 & ... & In`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `&` instead of a comma:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> void f(T n)
```

Comment: this seems to work; but why does switching the Number and Comparable<T> around result in an error?